# Accessing a published Google Sheets from a webpage

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a page with this code:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
xmlhttp.open("GET","https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/14EiO1Fq6Z9eiN03eejNMlPAISTmwwCLhtcZxoSqLszo/ovqq6ni/private/full",false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The code is failing due to:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.acme.com' is therefore not allowed access.

How do I solve this? I tried using the callback parameter but that just results in the same error.

Is the problem the way I'm retrieving the URL, or something on the Google Sheets / Spreadsheets end?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with your code? do you want to embed the spreadsheet in your webpage?

Comment: I just want to get access to the data from the spreadsheet and test if a certain value that I got from the user is contained in that spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this with using this URL:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/14EiO1Fq6Z9eiN03eejNMlPAISTmwwCLhtcZxoSqLszo/ovqq6ni/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=googleDocCallback